# Как сделать стоп будильника по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: java, android

Понимаю, что вопрос, скорее всего элементарный, но никак не могу додуматься сама.

Делаю простой будильник, но никак не могу сообразить как сделать стоп будильника по нажатию на кнопку.

Вот класс с Броадкастом:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(), notification);
        ringtone.play();
```

А кнопка в в основном классе.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам важна именно такая компоновка, то можете прикрутить к кнопке `sendBroadcast()` с каким-нибудь своим экшн ну и в ресивере уже определять, откуда пришёл вызов и что с ним делать (вкл/выкл рингтон). И в манифест не забудьте свой экшн добавить.

Comment: Спасибо. Компоновка не важна, главное, чтоб заработало.